# Strange behaviour of file.get() on mac os x

Tags: c++, macos, file

some strange behaviour occurred. So, i have program, which i just copypasted from cplusplus.com.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  char str[256];

  std::cout << "Enter the name of an existing text file: ";
  std::cin.get (str,256);    // get c-string

  std::ifstream is(str);     // open file

  while (is.good())          // loop while extraction from file is possible
  {
    char c = is.get();       // get character from file
    if (is.good())
      std::cout << c;
  }

  is.close();                // close file

  return 0;
}
```

In the same folder, where my program is, I have file named "hello.txt", which consist of 1 line "abc abc". 
So, after I run program and input "hello.txt", I have following line:

```
hsdhs131313dhhsd
```

Which is, of course, not the content of "hello.txt". I am using mac os x and clang for compilation. Where is the problem, why code sample from official site not working? Thank you in advance

Comment: Nothing looked overtly wrong with your program. So I compiled it on my Mac, setup hello.txt as described. It works fine for me, which I know does help.

Comment: Agreed; I think you need to re-test this, and ensure `hello.txt` contains the text you expect.

Comment: Not a good site if this is an example of code from it.  Your loop should read either `int c = is.get(); while ( c != EOF ) { std::cout << static_cast<char>( c ); }` or `char c; while ( is.get( c ) ) { std::cout << c; }`.  And there's no point in `is.close()` here; the file will automatically be closed when `is` is destructed.  (There _is_ a need for explicitly closing output files, since you have to check the status after the close.  But this doesn't apply to input files.)

Comment: You probably have more than one file named `hello.txt` and aren't opening the file you expect. Try specifying a full, absolute path.

Comment: @trojanfoe
No, there is one hello.txt, and it's filling wright.